# Errors compiling .s file on Apple Silicon

Tags: macos, assembly, x86

I'm having problems compiling some very simple assembly sketch with `gcc ... -m32`.
I've tried compiling the same code with the same command on a windows pc and everything works fine.
Here's what I obtain with `gcc --version`

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

**EDIT**

That's the sketch I'm testing

```
.globl f
f:
    movl $10, %eax
    ret
```

and the error

```
f.s:3:15: error: unexpected token in operand
    movl $10, %eax
              ^
f.s:4:5: error: invalid instruction
    ret
    ^
```

Comment: "Im' having problems..." How about explaining the problems. You tagged `x86` but your compiler target is `arm64`. Could that be your problem?

Comment: I thought specifying -m32 was enough, I’ve added some details di what I’m doing @JimRhodes

Comment: Your processor is incapable of executing x86 code and the toolchain you have is a toolchain for ARM.  You will not be able to assemble x86 code with it and neither will you be able to run it (except perhaps with Rosetta).